# Shift-and-or multiplication operation

Tags: algorithms, integers, number-theory, multiplication

Continuing in the same vein as [Carry-free multiplication operation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16578/2755), a followup question is as follows (differences in bold):

Let $r = p \oplus q$ be an operation similar to multiplication, but slightly simpler: when expressed via long-multiplication the columns aren't summed up, but rather **or**'d (not **xor**) together. Nothing is carried.

$$
  \left[\begin{matrix}
    &&p_n & ... & p_i & ... & p_2 & p_1 \\
    &&q_n & ... & q_i & ... & q_2 & q_1 & \otimes\\
    \hline\\
    &&q_1 \cdot p_n & ... & q_1 \cdot p_i
      & ... & q_1 \cdot p_2 & q_1 \cdot p_1\\
    &q_2 \cdot p_n & ... & q_2 \cdot p_i
      & ... & q_2 \cdot p_2 & q_2 \cdot p_1\\
    &&&&&&&...\\
    q_i \cdot p_n & ... & q_i \cdot p_i
      & ... & q_i \cdot p_2 & q_i \cdot p_1 & \stackrel{i}{\leftarrow}
      &&{\bigvee} \\
    \hline \\
    \\r_{2n}& ... & r_i
      & ... &r_4& r_3 & r_2 &r_1 & =
  \end{matrix}
  \right]
$$

Using the long-multiplication-style formulation, this takes $\mathcal O\left(\max\left(\left|p\right|,\left|q\right|\right)^2\right)=\mathcal O\left(\left|r\right|^2\right)$ time. Can we do better? Perhaps we can reuse some existing multiplication algorithms, or even better.

Comment: this is very similar to a problem known as "boolean convolution" in savages models of computation book....

Comment: @vzn can you link it here again?

Comment: Have you done any thinking about whether Karatsuba, FFT, etc. methods apply to this operation as well?  That'd be the first thing I would try.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to an operation known as *boolean convolution*. See *Models of Computation* page 419 defn 9.6.3.

Dunne states (p5):

> Weiss 1984 and Blum 1984b obtained lower bounds for the n-point boolean convolution function which is closely related to integer multiplication.

- [Models of computation](http://cs.brown.edu/~jes/book/pdfs/ModelsOfComputation.pdf)
- [Relationships between monotone and non-monotone network complexity,](http://books.google.com/books?id=inRYYffoS00C&pg=PA1) Dunne
- Blum, N. (1984b) An $\Omega(n^{4/3})$ lower bound on the monotone network complexity of *n*-th degree convolution; Theoretical Computer Science, 36, 59-70